# GitLab CI: echo isn't ignoring quotation marks

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Using Gitlab CI, I'm trying to use echo to write some XML and put it in a file. This is my echo statement:

```
- echo "<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package>
      (more xml stuff here)
    </package>" > myfile.xml
```

My issue is that the resulting xml file includes the opening and closing quotation marks. When I try running this echo command in a regular command line, it works just fine. Why does Gitlab include the quotation marks in the output? How can I fix this code to make it not do that? (When I try removing the quotation marks, it runs into an issue with the first < character.)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I need to put a ^ before each < and > character.